# Too much data (at a time) for Core Data?

Tags: ios4, core-data, ipod-touch

My iPhone app uses core data and things are fine for most part. But here is a problem:
after a certain amount of data, it stalls at first time execution (where core data entities must be loaded).

Some experimenting showed that things are OK up to a certain amount of data loaded in Core Data at start.
If I go over a critical amount the installation starts failing. The bigger the amount of data for start, the higher the probability that it fails.

By making separate tests I made sure the data themselves are not faulty.
I also can say this problem does not appear in the simulator.
It also does not happen when I connect the debugger to the device.

It looks like too much data loaded in core data in a short amount of time creates some kind of overload.
Is that true? Any idea on a possible solution?

At this point I made up a partial solution using a UIActionSheet object to kill some time (asking the user to push a button). But this is not very satisfactory, though for the time being it works.

Any comment or advice for a better way would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not quite clear what do you mean by "it fails".

However if you are using SQLite, by loading into CoreData, if you mean "create and save" entities at start up to populate CoreData, then remember to not call [managedObjectContext save...] only at the end especially with large amount of data, but create and save a reasonable set of NSManagedObject.

Otherwise, if you mean you have large amount of data that are retrieved as NSManagedObject, probably loaded into a UITableView consider using some kind of NSOperation for asynchronous loading.

If those two cases doesn't apply to you just tell us the error you are getting, or what you mean by "fails" os "stalls".

Comment: Thanks for the tip. But I ended up by solving my problem, using an NSTimer in order to cut the job into several pieces. Now it works fine.